# How to align label to left in extjs 7.1.0?

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

By default it is aligned to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry, this is easily solved!
Just click on the magnet on the left in the align configuration settings in the label component.
In the text before the word left, put a space. Then remove the magnet and save.